# How to offset dataObject from referenceObject using popper.js?

Tags: popper.js

How do I offset the `boat` from the `anchor` by a few pixels?

You can find a code pen where I have unsuccessfully tried to set an offset here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXraLK?editors=1111

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="anchor">Anchor</div>
<div class="boat">Boat</div>
```

CSS

```
.boat {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.anchor {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("anchor")[0];
var boat = document.getElementsByClassName("boat")[0];

var offsetTopModifier = function (data) {
  data.offsets.popper.top += 50;
  return data;
}

var popper = new Popper(
  anchor,
  boat,
  {
    placement: 'bottom-end',
    modifiers: [offsetTopModifier]
  }
);
```

This was the source that inspired my attempt:

https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

One work around was to set margins on the boat.